# Java get the second generic types

Tags: java, generics, reflection, parameterized-types

I'm struggling to get the type of second generic from an object.

The abstract class takes two Generic types T and S

```
abstract class Concept<T, S> {
    
    public Concept() { 
     //do nothing
    }

    public final Class<?> getTypeParam() {
    
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

        Class<?> result = (Class<?>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        return result;
    }               
}
```

In this derivative class one (in this case T) generic is defined:

```
public class Decision<S> extends Concept<String, S>{
    
    public Decision () {
        super();
        System.out.println(getTypeParam()); //returns the first parameterized type. How do I get the second one?
    }       
}
```

When I now run it I get the first parmerized generic back. Great. But how do I get out the second one?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Decision<Boolean> myBooleanDecision = new Decision<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `(Class<?>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[1];`?

Comment: when I change getActualTypeArguments()[1] I receive an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.Class (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl and java.lang.Class are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
 at main/model.Concept.getTypeParam(Concept.java:30)
 at main/model.Decision.<init>(Decision.java:11)
 at main/model.Main.main(Main.java:23)

Comment: Never put such information into **comments**. Always update your **question** instead. Nobody here wants to decipher stack traces from comments ...

Comment: And note: that exception is thrown in the Decision class. That class has only 1 generic parameter, so you cant ask for the **second**. You should rework your method to return a LIST of classes for example, and then return a List.

Comment: Finally: understanding how to work with arrays is basic java. Inspecting generic types ... is very advanced stuff. It seems you have trouble with the basic stuff ... so I seriously recommend: forgot about the advanced stuff for some time. Learn the basics first. If you dont understand why your code throws that exception, then these advanced topics will not work for you.

Comment: @GhostCat I do believe your comments are made in the best of spirit. The reason I put the exception in the comment was I responds to QBrute so he could see what his proposed solution does. So to the code in the question does not throw the exception. That is why I did not add the exception to the question. Sorry if that confused you to much.

Comment: @GhostCat: I think that second comment of yours here qualifies as an answer. It describes the problem and proposes a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is based on the fact that you aren't clear on your requirements.

Your method signature looks like this: `public final Class<?> getTypeParam()`

But what you overlook: the number of type parameters with your classes isn't fixed. The base Concept class allows for **two** type parameters, but the Decision subclass "fixes" the first parameter to String.

Thus: you have to decide what you actually want/need. There are various solutions, like:

- `public final Class<?> getFirstParam()` ... to return index 0, always
- `public final Class<?> getSecondParam()` ... to return index 1, always (which obviously fails for classes that only have 1 generic type parameter)
- `public final List<Class<?>> getParams()` ... to return a list with all entries

That is your option space. Which solution to pick solely depends on the purpose of that method (which *we* don't know anything about).

Personally, I would go for the third option, as that will work for 0, 1, ... n type parameters, without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the decleration:

```
Decision<Boolean> myBooleanDecision = new Decision<>("Binary Decision") {};
```

Now this will result in the second generic:

```
Class<?> result = (Class<?>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Output is:

```
class java.lang.Boolean
```